# Rewrite switch statements in java using if, else if, else

Tags: java, eclipse, switch-statement

I'm exploring another way of writing this instead of switch case statement. This basically controls to move an object from left to right and vise versa using left and right keys. I'm trying to write it in if,else if statement but having few syntax errors.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) 
{ 
    int key = k.getKeyCode();           
            switch (key) 
            { 
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    if (basket.getX() > 0) 
                    { 
                        basket.move(-BM, 0); 
                    } 
                    break; 

                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: 
                    if (basket.getX() + BW <  AW) 
                    { 
                        basket.move(BM, 0); 
                    } 
                    break; 
            }  
}
```

Comment: `if`, `else if`, `else`

Comment: Yup, just check `key == ` each possibility.  What is the purpose behind this question?  Is there something about `switch` that you don't like here?

Comment: @Riley CarneyThat's what I'd like to write it in but unsuccessful. Getting syntax errors

Comment: When you say `if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)` it gives you an error?

Comment: @Riley Carney yes thats where I my issue was. The solution above wrote it this way: if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative way :

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {    
    if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
      if (basket.getX() > 0)  { 
        basket.move(-BM, 0); 
      } 
    }

    if(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
      if (basket.getX() + BW <  AW) { 
        basket.move(BM, 0); 
      } 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is what I was looking for. I had some syntax errors when attempting to write this way. Its my first year of java. Still a noob. Thanks!

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. I couldn't get it to work prior making this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is always a way to minimize at the maximum but you'll lose in readability of the code.

I would personnaly prefer using a `switch` statement or an `if-else` when possible for the sake of readability.

---

### Solution

```
boolean keyLeftTrue = false;
if ((keyLeftTrue=(k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) && basket.getX() > 0)
        || (k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && (basket.getX() + BW <  AW))){
    basket.move((keyLeftTrue?-BM:BM), 0)
}
```